# Cannot getting data from external nested json file form jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get data from external nested json file.
this is my ajax call:

```
 <script>
var json1 = (function () {
  var json1 = null;
  $.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': "PlayerActivity",
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
      json1 = data;
    }
  });
  return json1;
})(); 


var temp1 = [];
$.each(json1,function(i,val){
  player = {};
  player.id = val.id;
  player.Events = val.Events;
  temp1.push(player);
});
  alert(temp1[1].Events); 

  $.each(temp1.Events, function(entryIndex, entry) {
       alert(this.desc); 
    });
</script>
```

this is my json format:

```
 var data1=   {
"id": "7",
"Events": [
    {
        "id ": "1",
        "desc": "kjbjhsdbjhbzsdj"
    },
    {
        "id ": "2",
        "desc": "kjbjhsdbjhbzsdj"
    },
    {
        "id ": "3",
        "desc": "kjbjhsdbjhbzsdj"
    }
  ]
}
```

When i do temp[1].id it shows correctly but when i do temp[1].Events, It shows undefined. I know i didn't define desc but i tried many ways like:

```
  player.Events.desc = val.desc
  player.desc = val.desc
```

etc..etc. but nothing worked

Comment: The problem is `json1` is not an array, it is a object so your loop `$.each(json1,function(i,val){` is not proper

Comment: put your temp[1] first

Comment: what is the need for the `$.each(json1,function(i,val){` loop in the first place

Comment: Try  player.Events[0].desc

Comment: json1 is not an array but I am passing temp1[] which is an array. should i use object in loop?

Comment: @BeingHuman thanks a ton. I was trying from last days its not working just beecause i didnt use  **player.Events[0].desc**. Its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
player.Events[0].desc
```

for more: https://www.json.com/json-object

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong, because AJAX call is asynchronous and you're getting undefined, because data wasn't loaded yet. You can provide a callback to AJAX request, or invoke a function on success. Try this one:

```
var invokePlayerActivity = function () {
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': "PlayerActivity",
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            main(data);
        }
    });
}; 

function main (data) {
    var temp1 = [];

    $.each(data, function(i, val){
        player = {};
        player.id = val.id;
        player.Events = val.Events;
        temp1.push(player);
    });

    alert(temp1[1].Events); 

    $.each(temp1.Events, function(entryIndex, entry) {
        alert(this.desc); 
    });
}

invokePlayerActivity();
```

Comment: I gave an answer bro. now its working. Just one line I need to change

Answer (score 0):

just you need to use this

```
   alert(**player.Events[0].desc**)
```

instead of

```
    alert(Events[0].desc)
```